# Does using the same bootstrap samples to calculate multiple estimators cause inappropriate correlation between the estimators?

Tags: bootstrap

Suppose I want to obtain a variance estimator from a bootstrapping.

The procedure for this may go like:

1. For a dataset of size $N$, create $B$ bootstrap samples (sampling from original dataset) of size $N$.
2. Calculate a statistic $\hat{p_i}$ for each $i \in B$.
3. Calculate the sample variance of the $\hat{p_i}$'s.

But if I wanted to get variance estimates for multiple parameters using the data (e.g. for several $\beta$'s in a regression model), is it appropriate to use the same bootstrap samples to calculate the each estimator? Or is it more appropriate to create a new family of bootstrap samples for each estimator? That is, can I calculate all the statistics in step 2, and the variance estimates in step 3, or do I have to repeat 1-3 for each variance estimator?

Intuitively, it seems to me that estimates calculated from the same family of bootstrap samples would share properties that estimates calculated from a different family of bootstrap samples would not.